# How do I get tkinter application to update as I change a text file needed?

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, while-loop, text-files

I have a text file with values that I need to display in a scroll box tkinter. I have been succesful in doing this but there is a problem. When I press submit to add more values to my text file in my program, the scrollbox displaying the contents in the text file does not update with the new values.

Here is a screenshot of the program:
[image: Here is a screenshot of the program:]

This is my text file:

```
amazon.com
username@gmail.com
n3*F/X"qse~a`_+

netflix.com
username@outlook.com
avOmCl|Jb?O<

apple.com
username@icloud.com
s=DT8n*Y"y
```

However when I press submit the text file updates with the values submitted but the scrollbox does not.

Here is my full code:

```
import string
import random
from tkinter import * 
import tkinter.scrolledtext as st 

mypasslist = []

with open("password&usernames.txt", "r") as input:
    for line in input:
        items = line.split()
        mypasslist.append([item for item in items[0:]])


def generatePassword():
    characters = string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation  + string.digits
    password =  "".join(random.choice(characters) for x in range(random.randint(8, 16)))
    return password

def writeToFile(input_variable):
    with open("password&usernames.txt", "a") as input:
        input.writelines(input_variable)

top = Tk()    
top.geometry("1920x1080")   

def ifSubmit():
    global a
    a = generatePassword()
    label1 = Label(top, text='Your password is: %s' % a, font=("Arial", 11)).place(x = 40, y = 170)
    label1 = Label(top, justify='left', text='Your password and username has been saved, you can access them below.').place(x = 40, y = 227)
    copy_button = Button(top, text = 'Copy', command=copyText).place(x=40, y=195)
    
    service = service_var.get()
    username = username_var.get()

    writeToFile('%s\n' % str(service))
    writeToFile('%s\n' % str(username))
    writeToFile('%s\n' % str(a))
    writeToFile('\n')

def copyText():
    top.clipboard_clear()
    top.clipboard_append(a)
    top.update()

# the label for user_name  
Service = Label(top, text = "Service").place(x = 40, y = 60)   
user_name = Label(top, text = "Username").place(x = 40, y = 100)   

submit_button = Button(top, text = "Submit", command=ifSubmit)
submit_button.place(x = 40, y = 130)

service_var = StringVar()
Service_input_area = Entry(top, width = 30, textvariable=service_var)
Service_input_area.place(x = 110, y = 60)
service = service_var.get()

username_var = StringVar()
user_name_input_area = Entry(top, width = 30, textvariable=username_var)
username = username_var.get()
user_name_input_area.place(x = 110, y = 100)

text_area = st.ScrolledText(top, width = 50, height = 10) 
  
text_area.grid(column = 0, pady = 260, padx = 40) 

for i in mypasslist:
    text_area.insert(INSERT, i)
    text_area.insert(INSERT, '\n')

text_area.configure(state ='disabled') 

top.mainloop()
```

So how could I make the program update every time new values have been submitted?

Comment: Where and when do you expect it to update.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, I had to do:

```
def writeToFile(input_variable):
    with open("password&usernames.txt", "a") as input:
        input.writelines(input_variable)
    text_area['state'] = NORMAL
    text_area.insert(INSERT, input_variable)
    text_area['state'] = DISABLED
```

Comment: I recommend changing the word `input` because it is a built in function name.

Comment: Thanks, for the tip. Will do.